# How to digitally draw webcomics like sintitulocomic.com using sketchbook pro

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, comics, autodesk-sketchbook-pro

I am a visual interface designer based in India. I design web/mobile screens in photoshop, do logos and stuff in Illustrator. Lately, I've come up with an idea of making a webcomic, like the one here - http://www.sintitulocomic.com/ - but I have no experience in drawing or sketching at all.

Also, I did google on how to make digital comics etc., but I was confused and couldn't get the complete step by step process for this.

I don't want to create fancy full colored comics like batman or spiderman, just basic 2 colored stuff like in the sin titulo's comic I mentioned above.

I recently have heard good word about sketchbook pro. Could anyone guide me on whether to begin sketching with a pencil or paper and then scan and ink and color or whether to directly draw on the computer using wacom pen tablets?

Comment: This question is too broad in that you are essentially asking how to draw and color comics. But to answer the question it looks like those are pen-and-ink drawings, then scanned in and colored that way.

Comment: I know the question is too broad. I want to know where do I begin to reach the result which would be something similar to sin titulo. Should i begin learning pen and ink drawings? Or would sketching directly using a pen tablet be a better way? I don't know how exactly to frame this question. But the basic thing is I have a concept and storyline for a webcomic in mind and I want to achieve that! Too vague I know :(

Comment: Pen and ink or digital? entirely a personal preference. I would say start with ink, but that might just be me. And practice, practice, practice is the only thing that counts.

Comment: You are over thinking this. It's art... there is no *wrong* way to create art. Grab whatever you like and start drawing.

Comment: Hello, I've narrowed it down to a question between drawing on pen and paper first or using sketchbook pro directly.

Comment: It's not so much about the tools, but learning and practicing to draw. That's the first step. Grab a pad of paper and a pencil and start sketching. Then sketch some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a pencil. Take a notebook. Start sketching. Once you are comfortable with that, try telling a story through your images. Once you are comfortable with that, then google specific techniques for making comics. But the two basic, fundamental things you have to learn is how to express a situation and a story through images.